# Is there a way to convert emf/wmf files to png/jpg in python?

Tags: python-3.x, png, wmf

I have to translate a docx document into a html file. The docx contains pictures that shall appear in the html. As some formats can't been displayed I have to convert images in a wrong format into a correct one.
I use pandoc to convert docx to html, then handle images one by one.
For example, I can identify a ".tiff" image and convert it to png to be displayed.

However I am struggling with a format called .emf or .wmf.

My process is to open the image file with PIL.Image then save it in an other format.
But I have an error telling me PIL didn't find a loader for this format.

After many research on internet, I only find not free API and not maintained libraries.

Does anyone know a way to convert emf files using python?

PS: I also tried Wand library after installing ImageMagick on my computer but got an error for format "wand.exceptions.MissingDelegateError: no decode delegate for this image format `EMF' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/575"

Comment: If you run `magick -version` it will tell you the list of image reading/writing delegates it has installed - so you need `EMF/WMF` to appear in that list. If it is not there, you need to install the `libwmf-dev` package and rebuild ImageMagick using `./configure ... --with-wmf`

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)